# Can molecules bend light?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, molecules

As we know, objects with a large gravitational field can bend light, but, my question is, Can molecules bend light? Since molecules have a small amount of gravity, couldn't they bend light in at least a small measurable amount?

Comment: I think the link was shortened, it takes me to a page about a furniture and architecture company.

Comment: Also, please post a answer instead of comment, I favor that more.

Comment: Please use a answer instead of comment, comments are for discussing it.

Comment: You don't have to criticize everything, but I will try to do more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there is no reason to believe that any amount of matter, no matter how small, fails to warp space-time according to the amount of its gravitational influence as indicated by the Einstein field equations. However, would that amount of space-time warp be measurable? No. absolutely not, at least not by today's experimental capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.